# Смена background картинки кнопки программным путем

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения, windows-phone-7, usercontrol

Доброго времени суток, Хэшкод.

Есть следующая проблема:
Существует WPF-User Control, на котором есть кнопки, описанные таким образом:

```
<Button MaxHeight="64" Name="bHome" {многаразныхпараметров}>
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/blahblahblah/menu_home.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
```

Есть необходимость при некоторых действиях, менять картинку этой кнопки (например, при заходе на home_page меняем картинку на другую или по клику на эту кнопку, меняем изображение).
Вопрос в том, как это можно сделать.

Я лично попробовал так:

```
Button source = (Button)bottomControlPanelMain.bHome;
            ImageBrush content = source.Background as ImageBrush;
            if (null != content)
            {
                content.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/blahblahblah/menu_home_active.png"));
            }
```

Но тут происходит забавный баг: я не вижу своей кнопки(sic!). Сама кнопка при этом работает.
 По логике, такое должно произойти, если не подгрузилась картинка к этой кнопке, но пошаговая отладка говорит, что
 картинка там есть. Ошибок тоже не возникает. Как такое может быть?

---

Обновлено.

Сравнил пути к файлу.
Старый:
[image]

А это новый:
[image]

Как видно, разница в "file://" у нового файла, все остальное совпадает. Имеет ли это значение?

Comment: Так может юри не правельный?

Comment: гм. Мне кажется, что если бы Uri был неправильный, то вылетал exception. А его нет. Собственно, там в одной папке лежат два файла с названиями menu_home и menu_home_active. У меня больше сомнения вызывает разница между ImageBrush и BitImage.

Comment: Чё та не вижу что при неправильном юри кидает ексепшен:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx

Comment: Попробуй ещё так:

    // Create source.
    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
    // BitmapImage.UriSource must be in a BeginInit/EndInit block.
    bi.BeginInit();
    bi.UriSource = new     Uri(@"/sampleImages/cherries_larger.jpg",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    bi.EndInit();
    // Set the image source.
    simpleImage.Source = bi;

Comment: Такс, проставил метку windowsphone7. @Чад предложеный вами код для winphone не работает. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Так если убрать file:// ? значение думаю имеет

Comment: Через дебаг напрямую убрать "file://" не получается, ибо "invalid expression term {" при попытке сменить Uri. Как можно сделать еще я пока не впилю. P.S. Все, решил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ:

```
content.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/MEMCOM;component/Resources/drawable/menu_home_active.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

**UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute** обязательно.

Записей типа: file://... быть не должно.

Comment: Сорри за оффтоп, но почему я не могу свой ответ принять?

Comment: Свои ответы нельзя принимать!

Answer (score 0):

VisualStudio 2017 "Blank App"

XAML

```
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="400,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.258,-5" Click="Button_Click" Height="80" Width="80"/>
```

C# (Set the original image in the properties of the button: right-click -> Brush -> image)

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Background = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:/Images/timerg.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) };

    }
```

or C#

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
            Uri u = new Uri("ms-appx:/Images/timer.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            bmp.UriSource = u;
            // NOTE: change starts here
            Image i = new Image();
            i.Source = bmp;
            button1.Content = i;
    }
```

Comment: Вас не смущает, что этот вопрос был задан больше 6-ти лет назад?